# Estimate of the absolute value of the probability amplitude of |0⟩ in the superposition

Tags: quantum-state, mathematics, textbook-and-exercises

You are given a source of an unknown qubit state. You make measurements in the computational basis, that is, your measurement is  $\{|0\rangle \langle0|,|1\rangle \langle 1|\}$. You observe that you see the outcome zero $30$ times and the outcome one $70$ times out of a hundred measurements. What is your estimate of the absolute value of the probability amplitude of  $|0\rangle$  in the superposition?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: To clarify, you want the full probability distribution for the amplitude given the data? Not just a single proportion.

Comment: Do you have any own thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes, basically an absolute value of the probability amplitude for 0 ket (an estimate is fine).

Comment: I think I actually worked it out thanks anyway guys

Comment: If you have worked it out, just put your answer. You can get yourself a Self-Learner badge. Someone else can expand on it if you miss anything, but it's good to answer your own questions.

Comment: Here is my answer: 0.547

Comment: @RahmanTurtle I agree with AHusain.  How did you get that answer?  I mean of course you just took the square root of $30/100$ but I think AHusain is saying actually put the answer into a separate reply, and not just a comment.

Comment: @RahmanTurtle, 0.547 is not an estimated but square root of measured value, however, we know that probability amplitudes can be complex numbers also and in such a case you have infinite number of them of which, 0.547 is one which is a pure real number. So the probability of 0.547 being the actual probability amplitude is very small. Second problem is - what is the probability that 0.3 is the actual probability of finding qubit in |0>. If you make more number of measurements or less number, do you still get the same ratio  of 3:7? cotinued in next remark..

Comment: Continued: In order to answer the above two questions, we would need more information two aspects.What is the evidence that 0.3 corresponds to a particular probability amplitude? Is measurement stationary process or WSS? Is it ergodic in nature?

Comment: @Ashish the OP asked for the *absolute value* of the probability amplitude, that is, a real number.

Comment: @MarkS, you are correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer 0.547
I got this through the square root of 30/100. as the probability of ket 0 to ket 1 as a fraction.

Comment: For what you missed, imagine you only make 10 measurements and get 0 3 times and 1 7 times. Your procedure would make the same estimate, but you should have more uncertainty.